# Excel VBA - Creating new sheet with categories and rows in between

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Objective: To have a Macro that has rows with content in one sheet separated by empty rows depending on the values of other sheets. Here is how the final output should look like:

[image: image from user]

Situation now (manual): I go to Sheet 3, see which categories exist, and add them manually on Sheet 1 with red background. Afterwards, I go to Sheet 2, see how many sub-items exist per category, and add that many rows manually in Sheet 1.

Picture of Sheet 2:

[image: picture of sheet 2]

Picture of Sheet 3 (Categories)

[image: sheet 3]

Situation with Macro: I run a macro which then creates the categories based on Sheet 3 and with empty rows between these categories based on the # of items in Sheet 2.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub AddingCategories()
'
' AddingCategories Macro
'

' here we copy the categories from the Categories sheet
    Sheets("Categories").Select                         'we select the sheet where the categories are
    Range("A1").Select                                  'we select the first cell with content
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select      'we can select all categories with content
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy                                      'we copy the content
    Sheets("Timeschedule2").Select                      'we go to the destination sheet
    Range("B11").Select                                 'We select the first row where we want content
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'Here we format them to red

    Range("A11:B25").Select                             'since we just copied content, we need to have the cells with the formatting we want (in this case red)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
'Here we delete all rows without content
    Range("B11:B30").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

'Here we add the rows. Since we want to specify a number of rows to add, we first calculate this value using a countif function
'this will tell us how many rows we need to add and we have it in Categories!C1. To add that many rows, we use a loop


For i = 1 To Worksheets("Categories").Range("C1")

Worksheets("Timeschedule2").Select
Rows("12:12").Select
Selection.Insert
With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Next i
End Sub
```

With this code, I very proudly created the categories and managed to create the number of rows for the first category. 
My problem is now that I don't know how to create the loop that will do this for all categories automatically (to do the first one, I specified to add them for row 12:12; but I have no way of knowing in advance where they should add the next new rows, nor how many times to loop since the number of categories will change from project to project) 
I've been searching with Do Until IsEmpty, Do While, For, etc.. but I haven't been able to figure it out.

How would you go about this? How can I improve my existing code?

I am aware that my code is probably very inelegant, apologies for that!
I'm primarily interested in learning how to program VBA more than making this particular macro work, so if you could explain to me as if I were a non-programmer 5 year-old I'd be thankful.

Comment: What is the logic that chose row `12` in the given example?  Ultimately, to tell a computer to do this, you need to have some deterministic way to identify the row.  Also, if possible, can you produce a second picture with the row and column numbers included?

Comment: I agree. the 12:12 was the first row I could use (where the categories should start), but it would be better if it was identified in a deterministic way. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Here is the picture of Sheet 2 http://postimg.org/image/pkbtit8dn/
Here is the picture of Sheet 3 (Categories) http://postimg.org/image/ei6qkdeaz/94034406/

Comment: Since this is based on `COUNTIF` you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` in VBA to get the same number.  You could alternatively just work your way through the current results on those sheets and use the formula result in the VBA.  Since this is based on labels matching, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` to figure out where on the sheet the given item/subitem is located.

Comment: Thank you Byron! This helps me further

Comment: Thanks @ByronWall for your tips, they helped me find the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it !

Instead of adding columns in between I just scroll down the number of spaces I need before pasting the new category. Let me know if I could improve the code even more

```
Sub NoDelete()
'This is done to make navigating the macro easier and avoid errors
Set cate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Categories")
Set times = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Timeschedule2")

'Instead of using Select (which increases errors) we use these variables to use the content of the cell we need
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range


'These counters are used for the loops to know how many rows we need
Dim RowCounter As Integer
    RowCounter = cate.Range("A1", cate.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Dim CateCount As Integer
CateCount = 0

Dim CateCount2 As Integer
CateCount2 = 0

Dim CateCount3 As Integer
CateCount3 = 0

'This is the loop which will repeat itself for as many times are there are categories in the categories sheet
For i = 1 To RowCounter
 'The offset is used to copy the next category and not the first each time, the counter will make sure it moves the appropriate amount of positions
    Set rng = cate.Range("A1").Offset(CateCount, 0)
    With rng
    rng.Copy
    End With

'for this one we tell where it should paste the value. For every new loop it needs to move more cells downward, which is why we use the CateCount 3
Set rng2 = times.Range("B11").Offset(CateCount2, 0)
With rng2
rng2.PasteSpecial
End With

'This looks complicated but it is only to format the backgrounf red
Set rng3 = rng2.EntireRow

With rng3.Interior
.Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With rng3.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 12
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    .Bold = True

End With

'The CateCount3 will count how many rows we need to add by counting how many times the category we are dealing with now
'defined by rng there is in the action sheet and then adding 1 one

CateCount3 = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("All actions Sheet").Range("C:C"), rng) + 1
'We need to add one unit to the counter so that for the next loop it will start one category below
CateCount = CateCount + 1
'The CateCount2 is used to add the right number of rows for the next loop
CateCount2 = CateCount2 + CateCount3
CateCount3 = 0


Next i  

End Sub
```